Trying to Track Down App Crash with No 1000/1001 Event ID Event Viewer Log Items and no Minidumps in %LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps
The title says it all.
I'm trying to diagnose an elusive app crash in my program that mysteriously leaves no traces in Event Viewer or the minidump folder.
It's obvious the program crashes since the system tray / notification area icon disappears when the mouse cursor hovers above it and the program is no longer running.
The program only crashes intermittently on my dad's computer running Windows 10. It's solid as a rock on mine and several other computers I've used my software on. Also I ran the program on my dad's computer attached to the Windows Debugger and it ran solid constantly for a month without any crashes. And the program left a minidump several months ago but I wasn't sure which version I was running so it's not of much use.
Any ideas?

Applications do not have to write dumps or to Event Viewer when they crash. We can assume you're talking about a Windows application, but which version of Windows? What application and what version of the application? If you open Task Manager and watch the application process, what happens as you repeat this behavior? Does the application have its own logging somewhere else? Please EDIT your post to add this and any other information that may be helpful to us to understand your problem and help you solve it.

You state "in my program," as if it's one you wrote. Did you include exception handling? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling

@music2myear Edited appropriately, thanks.

@DrMoishePippik This is my program and I have not included exception handling since I debugged everything already and there are no known bugs (there's gotta be a couple little guys here and there).

I don't think we can help, given the information you've shared so far. We could give some general suggestions, but not much else, and this site is specifically not for "general suggestions". I sympathize: apps that crash are frustrating, and app crashes that happen intermittently and unpredictably are the absolute worst. As the developer, you're responsible for integrating and enabling any logging that you appear to be looking for. I'd suggest you begin by doing that. Also, as this is a dev problem, I suggest that after you collect this further info, you post in StackOverflow rather than here.

@music2myear Thanks for the reply, can you point me to a tutorial to implementing the logging?
